# Scrapy - Scraping selected div

Tags: python, scrapy

the data i want to scrape is layed out like this:

```
<div class="ads__unit">
<div>2001</div>
<div>10 000</div>
<div>200 000</div>
</div>
```

There are multiple items with this div class. Im trying to scrape the first div within the add_unit div for every item. Is there a way i can select the first div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XPATH Selector:

```
//div[@class="ads__unit"]/div[1]/text()
```

CSS Selector:

```
div.ads__unit div:first-child
```

CSS Selector (Scrapy):

```
div.ads__unit div:first-child::text
```

Comment: Just to complement your answer, Scrapy includes some extensions on CSS pseudo-elements, so you can get text by using `::text` in the selector. More [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#extensions-to-css-selectors)

Comment: super, thanks exacly what i was looking for, do you have any docs you can show? Is there a second-child and third tag

Answer (score 0):

Ive found that you can use

```
nth-child(n)
```

to select the differnt div in the same class

Answer (score 0):

You also can use `get()` method to get first of element of list in any selector:

```py
response.xpath('//div[@class="ads__unit"]/div/text()').get()
```

or index nth the element of list

```py
response.xpath('//div[@class="ads__unit"]/div/text()').getall()[n]
```